# laravel route helper with resoures

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello I have this code

```
href="{{ route('task_types.update',['id'=>$type->id]) }}"
```

I expected task_types/{id}/update

but it always return task_types/{id}

so I always return to show page
any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing a array, not is necessary.

```
href="{{ route('task_types.update',['id'=>$type->id]) }}"
```

You create a resource route, create a get route:

```
Route::get("task_types/{id}/update", "youControler@update")->name('task_types_update');
```

try:

```
href="{{ route('task_types_update', $type->id) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If $type is a singular variable, then use this:

```
href="task_types/{{$type=>id}}/update"
```

If $type is a collection then iterate through them